# How can I mass-convert images saved as text/ascii in svn to binary?

Tags: svn, binary-data, corrupt-data

Somehow images got saved as text/ascii and I need to recursively do this for hundreds of directories of images, all under one root `images` directory.

I got some instructions [here](http://www.btaz.com/scm/svn-inconsistent-line-ending-style-when-trying-to-commit-a-binary-file/) which tell me to:

```
svn proplist <yourfile>
svn propdel svn:eol-style <yourfile>
svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream <yourfile>
```

Is there some native svn recursive way I can do this? If not, could someone advise how I could recursively apply this with a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the shell:

```
find -name '*.png' -exec \
sh -c "svn propdel svn:eol-style {} && svn propset svn:mime-type image/png {}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Subversion repository where I can test this out, but it shouldn't be too difficult:

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o print
```

This will list all of the files in your working directory (sans the .svn directories).

Now, you can combine this with a while read loop

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o print | while read file
do
   svn propdel svn:eol-style $file
   svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream $file
done
```

Now, you notice I'm not verifying whether or not the files have that property set or not. I simply don't care. And, this will do every file. If you want only to do a particular type of file, you'll have to modify the `find` command:

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o -name "*.jpg" print
```

I highly suggest you start with a clean Subversion working directory, and run a test like this:

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o print | while read file
do
   echo svn propdel svn:eol-style $file
   echo svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream $file
done
```

If the output of that looks good, then remove the `echo` and let 'er rip.

Answer (score 1):

The following powershell code will achieve what you're looking to do:

```
foreach( $file in get-childitem -name -include *.png -exclude .svn -recurse) {
    &  svn propdel svn:eol-style $file;
    & svn propset svn:mime-type image/png $file
};
```